# Table row add view takes up whole space

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, tablelayout, tablerow

What I am trying to achieve is to dynamically add views to a table row while the total width of the added views is less than the container's. If not, add the `TableRow` to the `TableLayout` and begin filling a new row. Each view consists of a `RelativeLayout` that has a `TextView` and an `ImageButton`. The problem is that the created `TableRow` always fills up all of the space. 
Here is the code:

```
    private void initializeTagWrapper() {
    //temperery tags
    mTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    mTags.add("Catastrophe");
    mTags.add("Another");

    //find it
    mTagWrapper = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.word_tag_wrapper);

    //the display size
    final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    int totalWidth = 0;

    TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));

    //mtags are already converted.
    if(mTags.size() != 0){
        //we have n amount of tags created. loop through them and add children to the layout
        for(int i = 0; i < mTags.size(); i++){
            /**
             * calculate the width of the screen
             * take the dimension of the first element and add it to size of this row
             * loop untill the size is greater than allowed, begin a new row
             */
            //create the layout
            View view = createView(i);

            //check if this one will fit
            if(totalWidth + view.getWidth() <= params.width * 0.95){
                //allow the parent to display this child
                row.addView(view);
                totalWidth += view.getWidth();
            }else{
                //push the row into the layout and nullify it + reset total width
                mTagWrapper.addView(row);
                row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                totalWidth = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
    private View createView(int position){
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.word_tag, mTagWrapper);

    //custom text view
    CustomTextView tv = (CustomTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.word_tag_name);

    //set the listener for the delete button
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.word_tag_delete);

    //set buttons click
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    //get the view's id
    view.setId(1000 + position);

    //set the textview text
    tv.setText(mTags.get(position));

    //return it back
    return view;
}
```

And here is the xml of the `View`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/application_item_margin_small"
android:background="@drawable/tag"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/word_tag1"
android:id="@+id/word_tag">

<com.ivanvoynov.dictionary.AppUtils.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/word_tag_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:text="Graph"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    app:customTypeface="@string/roboto_regular"
    android:textColor="@color/application_red_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_smaller"/>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/word_tag_name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/application_item_margin_medium"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:id="@+id/word_tag_delete"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
    android:background="@drawable/split_action_contextual_selector"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The xml for the holding `TableLayout` is:

```
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/word_tag_wrapper"
            android:layout_below="@+id/word_tag_header"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/application_item_margin_medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
```

And this is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `LayoutParams` on the `View` you're adding to the row rather than on the `TableRow` itself.

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

You'll see that I added a third parameter, which correspond to the `layout_weight`. So if all your `View`s have weight 1, the `sumWeights` parameter of your `TableRow` will be set automatically to the sum of them and they should be equally distributed in width within the space of your row.

Comment: It said you can't add `TableRow` layout parameters to a Relative Layout which is the container for my `View` thats added to the TableLayout

Comment: I updated my answer. You just have to replace `TableRow.LayoutParams` by `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.